# Definition of closed immersion.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is the definition of *closed immersion* given on Stacks Project.

[image]

In Hartshorne (II, Section 3), a closed immersion of schemes is only defined by the first two properties.  What does "locally generated by sections" mean?  And why is it considered to be an essential characteristic of a closed immersion?

Comment: Hartshorne defines this in the category of schemes, hence the map in (2) is a map of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$, hence the kernel is also quasi-coherent and thus automatically locally generated by sections, since it is locally of the form $M^\sim$ for a module $M$.

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by "locally generated by sections?"

Comment: Maybe it is too late now. But for the notion of *locally generated by sections*, one may turn to https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01B1 .

Comment: For the reason why the condition is needed, one may turn to the discussion at the begining of this section: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01C1 . The following post  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235752/ideal-sheaf-is-quasi-coherent-if-and-only-if-it-is-locally-generated-by-sections may helps when understanding the discussion in the Stacks Project.